Why does my if statement return false when using 'and not'?
I am trying to make a hangman game in python for practice(I'm pretty new to coding and a total newbie with python) When i try to check if a 'chosenLetter' is in 'randomWord' and not in the 'correctLettersUsed', it simply decides it is in there, even though it is not. When i loop through the while loop the first time, it does work as intended, but as soon as there is a letter in 'correctLettersUsed' and loop through it again, it does not.
#get random word from list
randomWord = wordList[random.randint(0, len(wordList))]

#counters and correct letters used
winAmount = len(randomWord) -1
correctLettersUsed = []
pointCounter = 0
wrongGuesses = 0

#loops until win conditions are met
while len(correctLettersUsed) != winAmount:

    #print for testing
    print(randomWord)

    chosenLetter = input("Pick a letter: ")

    #checks if the chosen letter is in the random word and not in the used letters
    if chosenLetter in randomWord and not correctLettersUsed:
        pointCounter += 1
        print("Correct!")
        correctLettersUsed.append(chosenLetter)
        print("Correct letters: " + str(correctLettersUsed))
    else:
        wrongGuesses += 1
        print("Incorrect. " + "You have " + str(6 - wrongGuesses) + " guesses left.")

I expect the if statement to be true. I have tried completely removing the 'and not correctLettersUsed' and then it works as expected. However, you could just use the same letter over and over again to win. All i can think of is that 'and not' just checks if there is anything inside of 'correctLettersUsed' and if this is the case, that would be true and the if statement would return false, i am not sure how to fix it. I have also tried using the vscode debugging tool but i really can't figure it out.

If you meant chosenLetter not in correctLettersUsed then you need to update the condition to if chosenLetter in randomWord and chosenLetter not in correctLettersUsed:. Currently not correctLettersUsed checks that correctLettersUsed is empty.

not correctLettersUsed will check if the list is empty, not if the letter is in the list

not correctLettersUsed is basically not [] for the first iteration.

This question is similar to: Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True? How can I compare "a" to all of those?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The logic should be
if chosenLetter in randomWord and chosenLetter not in correctLettersUsed:

otherwise it is interpeted as
if (chosenLetter in randomWord) and (not correctLettersUsed):

where any truthy (i.e. non-empty) list will evaluate to True

I tried it right away and now it works. I feel a little stupid but thank for for answering!

The if statement should be written like this to test for both conditions:
if (chosenLetter in randomWord) and (chosenLetter not in correctLettersUsed):

Currently your statement is checking if chosenLetter is in randomWord and if correctLettersUsed has a value. You're not checking if chosenLetter is in correctLettersUsed.
Hope that helps!

not correctLettersUsed will always return true because correctLettersUsed is a list.
you want it to say chosenLetter not in correctLettersUsed

The compiler can't guess that the and not phrase also is about the content of randomWord. The correct way is
if chosenLetter in randomWord and not correctLettersUsed  in randomWord :

correctLettersUsed is a list and lists are true when they are not empty.
So you original statement is only true when the correctLettersUsed  list is empty and chosenLetter is contained in the list randomWord
